# Can't import turtle

Tags: python, powershell, turtle-graphics

I'm a complete novice, so I appreciate the answers.
I'm trying to get turtle on my powershell, because that's what the book I'm reading says to do but this shows up,

```
import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ import turtle
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: i typed import turtle

Comment: `import turtle` is Python, not PowerShell.

Comment: what do you mean @Amadan

Comment: I mean it's like wondering why your washing machine is ruining your apple pie. You are using the wrong tool. If you want to use Python (and its `turtle` library), you should use Python. If you want to make PowerShell scripts, use PowerShell. You can't import `turtle` into PowerShell.

Comment: @Amadan: But my iron does a great job with my grilled cheese sandwiches. :)

Comment: And there's something to be said for sparkly-clean apple pie.

Answer (score 2):

You're not in the Python interpreter. You have to start it up, generally by entering the command `py`. Then you can use the Python environment.

Answer (score 1):

`import turtle` is Python but not PowerShell. Make sure you are in Python, not PowerShell, when you do `import turtle`.

Comment: Answers to questions are always appreciated. However, this question already had comments and an answer pointing out where the user had gone wrong.  You're time might be better spent answering as yet unanswered questions.